# Ionic release build error 2 modules

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Getting the following error when trying to run the command 
"ionic cordova build android --prod --release"

```
Type AcknowledgePage in C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/pages/acknowledge/acknowledge.ts is part of
            the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/app/app.module.ts and
            AcknowledgePageModule in C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/pages/acknowledge/acknowledge.module.ts!
            Please consider moving AcknowledgePage in
            C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/pages/acknowledge/acknowledge.ts to a higher module that imports
            AppModule in C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/app/app.module.ts and AcknowledgePageModule in
            C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/pages/acknowledge/acknowledge.module.ts. You can also create a new
            NgModule that exports and includes AcknowledgePage in
            C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/pages/acknowledge/acknowledge.ts then import that NgModule in
            AppModule in C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/app/app.module.ts and AcknowledgePageModule in
            C:/Projects/MobileApps/DOTPicking/src/pages/acknowledge/acknowledge.module.ts.
```

I tried to remove the Pages from the Declarations but that just results in another error. Is there a simple way to fix this error that I've just overlooked? When I remove them it basically just tells me to add them back.

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
    import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { MachinePage } from '../pages/machine/machine'
    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { LoginServiceProvider } from '../providers/login-service/login-service';
    import { DeviceStatusServiceProvider } from '../providers/device-status-service/device-status-service';
    import { EnvironmentService } from '../environments/environment.service'
    import { ModalServiceProvider } from '../providers/modal-service/modal-service';
    import { MachineService } from '../providers/machine-service/machine-service';
    import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list'
    import { GetworkPage } from '../pages/getwork/getwork'
    import { StagingPage } from '../pages/staging/staging'
    import { PickingServiceProvider } from '../providers/picking-service/picking-service';
    import { WeighpalletPage } from '../pages/weighpallet/weighpallet'
    import { ValidationServiceProvider } from '../providers/validation-service/validation-service';
    import { AcknowledgePage } from '../pages/acknowledge/acknowledge';
    import { NavigationMenuServiceProvider } from '../providers/navigation-menu-service/navigation-menu-service';
    import { PickPage } from '../pages/pick/pick';
    import { ScanlpPage } from '../pages/scanlp/scanlp'
    import { PickServiceProvider } from '../providers/storage-service/pick-service';
    import { ListServiceProvider } from '../providers/storage-service/list-service';
    import { SessionServiceProvider } from '../providers/storage-service/session-service';
    import { StorageHelper } from '../providers/storage-service/storage-helper';
    import { ReversePipe } from '../pipes/reverse/reverse';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        LoginPage,
        MachinePage,
        ListPage,
        GetworkPage,
        StagingPage,
        WeighpalletPage, 
        AcknowledgePage,
        PickPage,
        ScanlpPage,
        ReversePipe
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        HttpModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        LoginPage,
        MachinePage,
        ListPage,
        GetworkPage,
        StagingPage,
        WeighpalletPage, 
        AcknowledgePage,
        PickPage,
        ScanlpPage
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
        Device,
        AndroidPermissions,
        LoginServiceProvider,
        EnvironmentService,
        ModalServiceProvider,
        MachineService,
        DeviceStatusServiceProvider,
        SessionServiceProvider,
        PickingServiceProvider,
        ValidationServiceProvider,
        NavigationMenuServiceProvider,
        PickServiceProvider,
        ListServiceProvider,
        StorageHelper
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: remove AcknowledgePage form entry components.

Comment: same error after trying that

Comment: As the error says only import AcknowledgePage in AcknowledgeModule. Remove it from app.module

Comment: Simply import the AcknowledgeModule in imports in app.module.ts and remove the AcknowledgePage from the declarations and entry Components in the app.module.ts and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Ionic App release build Steps:-**

**Step1:-** Open cmd as Administrator then run following command:-

```
"keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000"
```

**Step2:-**Run command

```
ionic build android --release
```

it will create "android-release-unsigned.apk"

**Step3:-** Above step 1 command will create "my_private_key.keystore"
Make sure to save this file somewhere safe, if you lose it you won’t be able to submit updates to your app!

To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK:

```
"$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name"
```

**Step4:-** To find alias name run following command:-

```
"keytool -keystore my_private_key.keystore -list -v" at the root directory where keystore is placed.
```

**Step5:-** Zip align the resulting APK The zipalign tool is in the android-sdk/build-tools/{version}/ folder.

eg:-C:\Users\Karanvir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\25.0.2>

```
zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk android_release_signed.apk
```

Password of keystore:-android@123(here your password for keystore).

Enjoy!!!